# SQlite3 fts negate search

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, negation

Hi and thanks for looking!

I'm searching for articles which contain certain strings with full text search, something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles_fts WHERE body MATCH 'monkey OR banana OR "hungry gorilla"';
```

My real search is much longer (22 terms) and probably not the smartest way of doing this but it's working so no problems there.

**What I need help with...**
Now I want to return the OPPOSITE of what this search returns. In other words I want all the articles that don't contain monkey, banana, or "hungry gorilla".

Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

NOT is available only when SQLite was compiled with the [enhanced FTS query syntax enabled](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2).

Otherwise, you can use SQL set operations to negate the result:

```
SELECT *
FROM Articles
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT docid
                 FROM Articles_fts
                 WHERE body MATCH '...')
```